# Azure Data Factory: Inconsistent ordering of results after copy activity inside foreach activity

Tags: sql, data-warehouse, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse

I am trying to populate a fact table for a data warehouse in Azure Data Factory.

In the process, I am using the lookup activity which looks up a database table and outputs each row one by one to the foreach activity. The input to the foreach activity looks like:

[image: Pipeline]

Inside the foreach activity, I have a copy activity. In this copy activity, using the values of `Model` and `Make` for each row from the lookup activity, I use the query below to search my dimension table for the primary key `Car_ID`:

[image: Query used inside the copy activity to search for primary key:]

I get the correct `Car_ID` from the dimension table and copy it to a blank table, which I intend to copy to my fact table. I am able to get this to work perfectly but the only issue is that the order gets jumbled up in my `sink` table, which is the blank table. The source table is the dimension table I have mentioned earlier. Debugging the pipeline run tells me the input to the foreach is in the desired row-wise order and the corresponding `Car_ID` primary key obtained from searching is also correct; however, while copying the `Car_ID` to `sink`, I lose the order, which is necessary to maintain as I want to copy this resulting column to my fact table.

**Output from lookup/Input to foreach:**

[image: Output from lookup/Input to foreach]

I would really appreciate it if anyone could point out why it is happening or suggest a way to fix this.

Comment: Can you update your question with the structure of your source table? E.g., column names and types, either in a [MD table format](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/356997/new-feature-table-support) (preferred) or as a screenshot?

Comment: Did you know that by default the For Each loop in ADF executed in parallel?  Is your process designed to handle this?  If not, you can set the ‘Is Sequential’ property of the For Each activity but then you are losing out on one of the major benefits of the activity - ie the ability to execute in parallel.

Comment: Hi, I assume that your "sink" is a table in a relational DB? If this is the case then there is no concept of an in-built order to the records in the table. If you query the table, the records could be selected in a different order every time you run the query. If order is critical to your process then you need to add a column that explicitly defines the order (e.g. a sequence number) you want to maintain and then ORDER BY that column in any query

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Please click the **Sequential** in For Each active settings:
[image]

[image]

I tried and here's the result comparation:
[image]

HTH.